# Warning when HTTP used instead of HTTPS

Tags: ssl, https, cherrypy

I have a pure CherryPy server which has been running for a few years already.  I decided recently to add SSL support.  In this case it was enough to provide the certificate and key files and to assign correct values to the variables `cherrypy.server.ssl_certificate` and `cherrypy.server.ssl_private_key`.

I would like to give a warning about this change whenever somebody tries to access a page using "http://..." instead of "https://...".  Is there a simple way of achieving this without many changes in my system?  Another option would be to redirect the HTTP access to HTTPS—can that be done easily?

Answer (score 3):

I would create a custom handler to achieve what you're after.  This automatically redirects to HTTPS.

```
class Functions():
    def check_ssl(self=None):
        # check if url is in https and redirect if http
        if cherrypy.request.scheme == "http":
            cherrypy.HTTPRedirect(Referer.replace("http:", "https:"))

    cherrypy.tools.Functions = cherrypy.Tool('before_handler', check_ssl)
```

Comment: Is there really no "if HTTPS is 'on'" type thing?  You can't trust the referer for much of anything...this seems kinda dangerous.

Comment: Actually there *is* such a thing.  Check out `cherrypy.request.scheme` for a less flaky alternative.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I didn't know about scheme.